# Image a Background using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to add an image as a background for my beginners website, but producing just a white background.  I can change it to a specific colour using hex codes, but doesn't like the image.  I'm using Bootstrap as well, so not sure if that is interfering.

I'm sure this is a frustratingly easy solve, but I've spent like two hours on this looking at online resources.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-image: url(http://cdn1.theweek.co.uk/sites/theweek/files/2016/01/160114-kangaroo.jpg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<body/>
```

Comment: if your site is empty you won't see the image, as the height of body will be 0. YOu may add `height:100vh` to body. Or check the path of the image

Comment: Try this `background-image: url('img/mybackground.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: center`; And in order to use the custom font, you must include it in the `<head>` first.

Comment: put the css inside the head tag and see if it is working.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have <body> contents within the HTML, but I just haven't shown it above.

Comment: I think it’s due to the image’s url needing to be relative to the css file. The way you have it setup now I believe it’s looking for the ‘img’ directory inside of the ‘css’ directory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @SidTheBeard. New to all this, sorry.

Comment: I can implement it fine through the HTML, but not through the CSS.

<body style="background-image: url(img/myBackground2.jpeg); background-size: cover;">

Comment: Yeah, then I’m pretty sure it’s due to the path. In your html that path to the image will work because your html file is in the same directory as ‘img’. Just use this in your css... `url(‘../img/mybackground.jpg’)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `background: url('your_img_path')`, if still cannot see the image check the console for correct path.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/300x300') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Seriously? An image that says "placeholder"? Use `https://placehold.it/500x500` instead, where `500x500` is the specified `width` and `height`. It can be any resolution you want.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović check the updated answer, used the proper placeholder.

Comment: That's better. But you don't even need the `http:` you can just type `//placehold.it/300x300` that's even less typing.

Comment: well, yeah you can in case you are not hoping for cors issues.